# Avoid Home Page Load after refresh from some other page using Jquery and PHP techniques

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I am using following techniques to Load different pages with menu bar. When ever i click on any menu bar button it loads the pages without page refresh. But When I am in any other page except Home Page and i want to refresh or submit that page it again loads Home page.

**Menu**

> `<ul id="navigation">
>             <li><a href="javascript:loadContent(1);">Home</a></li>
>             <li><a href="javascript:loadContent(2);">Services</a></li>
>             <li><a href="javascript:loadContent(3);">About</a></li>
>             <li><a href="javascript:loadContent(6);">Contact</a></li>
>         </ul>`

**Jquery PageLoad**

> `function loadContent(id) {
>           $("#pagehandler").load("loadpage.php?pageid="+id+"");
>       }`

**Page Load in Body**

> `<div id="pagehandler"></div>`

**php file code**

> 

```
switch($cOption) {
    case 1: 
        $extra = 'home.php';
        header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra"); 
        break;
            case 2:
        $extra = 'Services.php';
        header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra"); 
        break;
            case 3:             
        $extra = 'about.php';
        header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra"); 
        break;


    default:
        echo 'Whoops, didn\'t understand that option: <i>'.$cOption.'</i>';
}
```

?>`

**From this sample code you can understand the process of code execution. When i click ony menu button.**

***How can i refresh any page using f5 with loading home page.***

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you the first branch of the switch statement is executing. Have you verified this?

I would have the home redirect be the default and only check for known values that are no home.

Comment: yes, i just noticed that. every its getting pagid=1 every time refresh that page.

Comment: I think your switch statement is always evaluating $cOption to equal 1. Can you show me the code you use to generate $cOption?

Use pastebin.com if it is too long